# How to create a dynamic popup Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, chocolatechip-ui

I found this Jquery mobile popup example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../chui/chui-3.9.0.js"></script>

$(function() {      
    ///////////////////
    // Initialize Popup
    ///////////////////
    $("#openPopup").bind("singletap", function() {
      $.UIPopup({
        id: "warning",
        title: 'Attention Viewers!', 
        message: 'The performance of "Merchant of Venice", Act 4 scene 1, will begin shortly. Thank you for your patience.', 
        cancelButton: 'Skip', 
        continueButton: 'Stay', 
        callback: function() {
          var popupMessageTarget = document.querySelector('#popupMessageTarget');
          popupMessageTarget.textContent = 'Thanks for staying with us a bit longer.';
          popupMessageTarget.className = "";
          popupMessageTarget.className = "animatePopupMessage";
        }
      });
    });             
});
```

Image element: 
    img src='images/Google-Maps.png' id='openPopup' />

I have about another 10 image elements which are populated dynamically (id="openPopup", id="openPopup1",id="openPopup2",...etc). The image elements should display the popup with different contents. How can I attach the function dynamically to each element !!

chui-3.9.0.js can be found here:
https://github.com/sourcebits-robertbiggs/chui/blob/master/dist/chui/chui-3.9.2.js

Comment: At first glance, I'd say use a common class rather than sequential IDs. Then bind the popup action to that class, e.g. `$(".openPopup").bind(...)`.

Comment: and how can I change the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind the popup action to multiple images, I suggest using a single common class rather than sequential IDs.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".openPopup").on("click", function() {
    $('#output').text($('#output').text()+'Clicked! ');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/1/" class="openPopup" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/2/" class="openPopup" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/3/" class="openPopup" />

<div id="output"></div>
```

To change the popup's content depending on which element was clicked, I suggest using one of the following methods:

1. Reference a JavaScript object that you've previously populated.

   Use jQuery's [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to identify the position of the clicked element in the set of selected elements. Use that integer to reference the relevant portion of your JavaScript object.

   ```js
   var popup_data = {
     '1': {
       'title': 'Title #1',
       'description': 'Description #1'
     },
     '2': {
       'title': 'Title #2',
       'description': 'Description #2'
     },
     '3': {
       'title': 'Title #3',
       'description': 'Description #3'
     }
   };

   $(function() {

     $(".openPopup").on("click", function() {
       
       var index = jQuery(this).index(),
           this_data = popup_data[index];
       
       $('#output').html(this_data.title + "<br />" + this_data.description);
       
     });

   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/1/" class="openPopup" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/2/" class="openPopup" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/3/" class="openPopup" />

   <div id="output"></div>
   ```
2. Read values from data attributes.

   Use jQuery's [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to access various data attributes of the clicked element.

   ```js
   $(function() {

     $(".openPopup").on("click", function() {
       
       var $this = jQuery(this),
           title = $this.data('title'),
           description = $this.data('description');
       
       $('#output').html(title + "<br />" + description);
       
     });

   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/1/" class="openPopup" data-title="Title #1" data-description="Description #1" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/2/" class="openPopup" data-title="Title #2" data-description="Description #2" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/3/" class="openPopup" data-title="Title #3" data-description="Description #3" />

   <div id="output"></div>
   ```

I haven't included Chui in my demonstrations, but the concepts should still be applicable.